# PHP conditions in ajax

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

The code below is part of an ajax script. Everything else is working perfectly except what is below.

I have no idea why this is happening :

```
$q_e = mysqli_query($sqllink,"SELECT * FROM events_parent WHERE id='$id_parent'");
$r_e = mysqli_fetch_array($q_e);

if($id_cure == $r_e['id_cure']){
    $same = 1;
}else{
    $same = 2;
}
if($same == 1){             //condition A
    # cure is the same
    mysqli_query($sqllink,"UPDATE events_parent ... ")

}elseif($same == 2){       // condition B
    # cure is changed
    mysqli_query($sqllink,"UPDATE events_parent ...")
}
```

No matter what the value of $same is, the my code still goes into condition A when it should just go into condition B. Even if i stop the script like this :

```
if($id_cure == $r_e['id_cure']){
    $same = 1;
}else{ 
    $same = 2;
}

echo "same : $same";
exit();
```

It outputs "same : 2", it does the mysql update correctly set in condition B but it also does the update set in condition A.

What am I doing wrong ? I tried using "===" instead of "==" but not result... Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: I didnt' understand...  are both query executed (A and B)? (ref:It outputs "same : 2", it does the mysql update correctly set in condition B but it also does the update set in condition A.)

Comment: Yes both query are executed, not matter what $same is... and id_cure is correct i printed the result..

Comment: `$id_cure` from where it is coming from?

Comment: @Baac if both are executed, show us the rest of the code yo hide behind your ..., their seems to be an error

Comment: If both the query are executed there is anything wrong in the code's structure. $same can be 1 OR 2, not both, so you must check for these issues:

Is there any syntax error in if...elseif statement?
is The UPDATE query in condition b right? Can that query update the rows in the same way of condition A? Try that in a phpmyadmin or in sql shell.
Maybe is this code in a function\method that is called more than one time?

Comment: @AndreaPosadino you were right, my ajax php page was being called more than once... I just noticed it now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction !